# Where does javascript store variables and how long are they kept?

Tags: javascript

This might be a bit general but, I'm wondering where are js variables stored? And are they kept when you click into new pages or every time the data is reset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are reset every time you refresh.

There are multiple ways to persist them between reloads. e.g.

- Webstorage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage
- cookies
- You save them to the database and load them into a session. Then render server side.

For all of these methods you would need to persist these (generally due to some user interaction) and load these on page reload etc. It does not happen automatically, you have to explicitly do so.

Comment: What if I want to keep some variables?

Comment: you'll need to roundtrip them to the server; consider using sessions or cookies for storing persistent state, e.g. [the document.cookie api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: @OneZero [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/), cookies, or your own DB.

Comment: It depends what server side technology you are using if it is ASP.Net you can also store it on the page viewstate as well

Comment: @Kiarash I'm assuming this isn't a simple postback scenario.

Comment: Actually due to memory leak, the values can still exist between refresh, but they are no longer accessible via JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

They stored in client memory and as Basarat mentioned they gone on each postbask or refresh

Comment: the whole description was not there when I commented at that time the sentence was just this "They are reset every time you refresh."